# Имя глобальной переменной и внутренней функции одинаковы норм?

Tags: javascript

```js
function makeCounter() {
  var currentCount = 1;

  // возвращаемся к функции
  function counter() {
    return currentCount++;
  }

  // ...и добавляем ей методы!
  counter.set = function(value) {
    currentCount = value;
  };

  counter.reset = function() {
    currentCount = 1;
  };

  return counter;
}

var counter = makeCounter();
```

Comment: В данном конкретном случае всё хорошо, потому что нет пересечений областей видимости, но лучше избегать подобных ситуаций и называть переменную в последней строке `counterInstance`

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach, что ты имеешь ввиду под _пересечением_? `var  counter` во внешней области и он вполне виден внутри `makeCounter`, так что пересечение вполне есть.

Comment: @Grundy В данном случае не имеет никакого значения, так как объявление глобальной переменной происходит после того как объявляется внутренняя функция с тем же названием. Пересечения нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Язык позволяет называть переменные как угодно, в соответствии с правилами.

Значение связанное с именем будет искаться последовательно поднимаясь в областях видимости пока не будет найдено соответствие, либо пока ничего не будет найдено включая в глобальной области.

Поэтому в данном случае такое именование вполне допустимо.

С точки зрения разработчика лучше давать более осмысленные имена, чтобы потом не путаться какая переменная за что отвечает.

Comment: а вот var counter = makeCounter(); makeCounter() возвращает результат counter; получается  var counter = counter будет норм правильно ?

Comment: @xes, ты неверно рассуждаешь, когда ты делаешь `var counter = makeCounter()` - это не значит `var counter = counter`

Comment: что после return возвращается () означает вернуть результат и возвращается функция counter

Comment: @xes, я не понимаю что ты пишешь, просто набор слов какой-то получается.

Comment: функция в скобках () возвращает результат; по другому возвращает return

Comment: return перед функции counter значит вернет функция под названием counter

Comment: _по другому возвращает return_ - Это как-то совсем по другому. При вызове функция возвращает результат. На этом можно закончить. Что у нее при этом внутри происходит - не важно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87903/discussion-between-grundy-and-xes).